# Count optional properties in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to count all properties who are not nil?

For example:

```
class test {
   var val1:Int?
   var val2:Int?
   var val3:Int?
   var val4:Int?
   var val5:Int?
}

var test = test()
test.val1 = 1
test.val2 = 2
```

How to find out that 2 properties are set? I could check for each one with (!= nil) - but is there an easier (and better) way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this manually, with a convenience method:

```
func numberOfNonNil() -> Int {
    let vals = [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]
    return flatMap { $0 }.count
}
```

`flatMap(_:)` takes a closure that takes a single element of the array and returns an optional value (`Element -> T?`), and returns the result of applying that closure to each element of the array, with `nil` values ignored.

The only way to make this simpler would be to store your values as an array of optional `Int`s in the first place:

```
class Test {
    var vals: [Int?]
}
```

You can then still access each individual value using the array subscript notation (`let val2 = vals[1]`). You could then just use the second line in the convenience method above (`filter` then `count`) to get the number of non-nil values:

```
let nonNilCount = vals.flatMap { $0 }.count
```

---

If your values are of different types, this approach will still work if you cast the array to a type that encompasses all the different types:

```
class Test {
    var val1: Int?
    var val2: Double
    var val3: String
    var val4: MyRandomClass?

    func numberOfNonNil() -> Int {
        let vals = [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5] as [Any?]
        return flatMap { $0 }.count
    }
}
```

This works because all the values can be expressed as the type `Any?`.

Comment: You could also replace `vals.filter { $0 != nil }` by `vals.flatMap { $0 }` because flatMap automatically ignore nil values.

Comment: @Fantattitude Good point. I'll change that in the answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: One thing. Just in my example all values are integers - but in my real life scenario ill got different optionals (such as strings, integers, floats, doubles and other classes - so i am not really able to combine that) - but its a good answer for someone with the same requirements.

Comment: Yeah sure :) Glad I could help improve the answer

Comment: @derdida That's fine, you just need to explicitly downcast your array to a type that can contain all the different types (`Any?`, as the name implies, will work for any optional type). See the edit above.

Comment: @Stuart - already done that! Thanks for this answer. Helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this, but you can implement your own function like this:

```
class test {
    var val1:Int?
    var val2:Int?
    var val3:Int?
    var val4:Int?
    var val5:Int?

    func setVarsCount() -> Int {

        var setVariablesCount = 0

        if val1 != nil {
            setVariablesCount++
        }

        if val2 != nil {
            setVariablesCount++
        }

        if val3 != nil {
            setVariablesCount++
        }

        if val4 != nil {
            setVariablesCount++
        }

        if val5 != nil {
            setVariablesCount++
        }

        return setVariablesCount

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - thats the solution i was thinking about it - but there are about 30 optional properties - and i am a little bit lazy here - Thought there is something more "Swift" :)

Answer (score 1):

@Stuarts answer is good, but you have to know the properties of the class, and if you add another property to the class, you also have to modify your method. To avoid this problem, you can use reflection, like

**Swift 1.2**:

```
func numberOfOptionalProperties() -> Int {
    let mirror = reflect(self)
    var numberOfOptionalProperties = 0

    for index in 0..<mirror.count {

        if mirror[index].1.disposition == .Optional {
            ++numberOfOptionalProperties
        }
    }
    return numberOfOptionalProperties
}
```

**Swift 2.0**:

```
func numberOfOptionalProperties() -> Int {
   return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.reduce(0) {
        Mirror(reflecting: $1.value).displayStyle == .Optional ? $0 + 1 : $0
    }
}
```